# Kotlin - How to write Code to get "Sum of all divisors of an integer"

Tags: kotlin, integer

**Hallo,**
i am very new to Kotlin and one of my task is write a Code to get Sum of all divisors of an integer. Its doesnt matter which Interger to use.
First Approach is with Imperativ Style and Second is with Collektion Function in functional Style.

I did write many Programm like Simple Banking, Sorted list or simple Elevator programm but that task confuse because i am not a Math Guy.
My Idea is to creat a value like "2" and make some divisior in a For loop or like that.

Hope i dont sound like a Stupid Guy.

Hope you can help me.

Thx for your Effort and Time.
Live Long and Prosper

Comment: Did you attempt anything yet? This is so open-ended, I don't know exactly what you need help with.

Comment: A Code to calculate the sum of all divisors of an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Imperative

val number = 100

var divisorSum = 0
for (i in 1..number) {
  if (number % i == 0) {
    // divisorSum += (number / i)
    // or shorter – see @Tenfour04's comment:
    divisorSum += i
  }
}

println(divisorSum)


// Functional

val number = 100

val result = (1..number)
  .filter { number % it == 0 }
  // .sumOf { number / it }
  // or shorter – see @Tenfour04's comment:
  .sum()

println(result)
```

Comment: Thx you very much. How it would looks like if i want to get result stept of the number that Code calculate? Like NUmber 12 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12??

Comment: val result = (1..number).filter { number % it == 0 }

Comment: `.sumOf { number / it }` could just be `sum()`. The sum of the divisors is the same as the sum of the complements of the divisors. Same thing applies to your imperative solution.

Comment: at Functional i get result 217 and at imperativ i did some change an get "1
2
4
5
10
20
25
50
100
217" How i can change Code from Functional to get same result as Imperativ?

Comment: Replace `.sum()` with `.let { it + it.sum() }`.